# Search and replace old links with new structure

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, sublimetext

Switching from server and CMS, I need to update the old links with the new file structure.

I have a dump from the database with more than 1500 wordpress posts. Each post has text, images and pdf links.

I want tje new URLs to look like: `/uploads/pdfs/foobar.pdf`

However, the old site's structure was disorganized:

- `/docs/actus/2008%20_10/foobar.pdf`
- `/docs/actus_25/joijdf%20sdij/foobar.pdf`
- `/docs/foobar.pdf`
- `/docs/2007/janvier10/foobar.pdf`
- etc

So I was wondering if it was possible to replace `*/docs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/*foobar.pdf` by `*/uploads/pdf/*foobar.pdf`

Is there any way I can do this with Sublime Text or Notepad++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested in Sublime Text 2:

Find `/docs/.*?([^/]+\.pdf)`.

Replace `/uploads/pdf/$1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I was dealing with multiple file extensions I did a small modification.
Find `/images/.*?([^/]+\.([0-9a-z]{1,3}))`
Replace `/uploads/$2/$1`
Thanks @tenub

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regex like `[/][\w\W]+[/]` to match the first part of the string